# HttpPost doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my view

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.User
....
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("CalisanEkle", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Adı</label><br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Soyadı</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mail Adresi</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MailAdress, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Çeviri Türü</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Teknik.Value, false)Teknik
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Medical.Value, false)Medikal
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Hukuk.Value, false)Hukuk
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default">Kaydet</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Sil</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row (nested) -->
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body -->
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    WebApplication6.Models.Entities db = new Models.Entities();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CalisanEkle(User kisi)
    {
        db.User.Add(kisi);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult CalisanEkle()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now on my submit button's click it should run the `[HttpPost]` controller right? Well, it does not run that. It runs the get controller. I used a breakpoint to make sure it does not enter the post lines. Tried multiple things for hours. Can someone help me please?

Model

```
public partial class User
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public User()
    {
        this.Lang_User = new HashSet<Lang_User>();
        this.Login = new HashSet<Login>();
        this.Projects = new HashSet<Projects>();
        this.WorkLoad = new HashSet<WorkLoad>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string MailAdress { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CompanyID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> PC { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Admin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Cevirmen { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Reductor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Teknik { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Medical { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Hukuk { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Lang_User> Lang_User { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Login> Login { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<WorkLoad> WorkLoad { get; set; }
}
```

web.config.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI. I corrected the second line m.surname but my problem is not about database anyway

Comment: can you share User model ?

Comment: sorry addded model again my brain turned into mashed patatoes

Comment: Why do you have name twice? in your view

Comment: You should have some error handling. like if(Model.isValid){ //do something};

Comment: But he said the breakpoint not hit inside CalisanEkle action.

@YunusEmre don't hit breakpoint inside CalisanEkle right ?

Comment: @japheren naicker i corrected it look at the first comment

Comment: the breakpoint is on   public ActionResult CalisanEkle(User kisi) line

Comment: when you run is breakpoint hit ?

Comment: no the break point does not hit

Comment: Is your Controller Name Home?

Comment: HomeController yes

Comment: can you add your all HomeController please

Comment: added HomeController

Comment: i am back no ideas? ty guys anyway you have been more than helpful

Comment: The code you have shown will not go to the GET method - it will go tp the POST method. If its not, its dues to code you have not shown us. But there are other errors in you code, for example your `CheckBoxFor()` methods - you cannot bind a checkbox to a nullable `bool`

Comment: i will try that in morning and post update

Comment: The code you published also worked for me after fixing issue with "SurName". My suggestion is: check for Javascript code attached to submit button. Open browser inspection tool and go to Network tab. It should say form is being submitted by `POST`. This would give you clue where to look next. If it says "POST" then problem may be at server side. If it says "GET" it might be js code doing something nasty.

Comment: ok so i removed checkboxes in case they are the problem no fix checked modelstate it is vlaid used fiddler to check and it says 200 get how can i check if it was the js code?

Comment: i removed every js code and run it nothing changed still 200 get

Comment: If browser is sending GET, there's something wrong on the page. When you inspect Html `form` tag in your browser, how does it look? Can you see more than one form tag? Are you sure no js attached?

Comment: İ am out but i just remember something blury my renderbody might cause the problem you mention i will check asap and update you

Comment: @derloopkat ty for that that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'am apologizing from everyone who tried to help me. My dumb *ss put the renderbody inside a form in layout page. This is what happens when you don't give a break you miss very obvious things.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="page-wrapper" style="min-height: 904px">

           @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </form>
```